# Which is better performance: to import once and pass as props to <Row/> or import within each <Row/> component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I guess the general question would be, does it require more handling to pass `something` as props to `<Child something={something}/>` or to `import something` within `<Child/>`.

So for example, I have:

```
import { baseStyle } from '../styles/common.js';

<FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSource}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>

renderItem() {
  return (
    <CustomRow
      baseStyle={baseStyle}
    />
  )
}
```

Or would it be better to `import baseStyle` within the `<CustomRow/>` component?

I would assume that at least for any `<List/>` component, React/RN would be smart enough to cache all the imports for the `<Row/>` components until it has finished rendering every `<Row/>`.

Does anyone have any theories about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was actually quite simple to test this out. What I did was I set a variable

`var time = Date.now();`

outside of the class above the `import` statements and then I console logged `time` in `componentDidMount()`. What showed was the same time registered to the first `Date.now()` assignment to `var time`, every time the component re-rendered. I think it's safe to assume from this behavior that if it's possible to just import a constant, to do that instead of passing it down as props which components recheck due to potential updates.